# How to select value from second column if first column is blank/null in SQL (MS SQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me build a SQL query where if column1 is null/blank I should get value from column2, if column2 is also blank/null I should get value from column3.

Below is the table that I am using

```
Price1   Price2   Price3

120

          140

                 160
```

The output that I am looking for is

```
Price

120

140

160
```

I have already tried

```
select Price1 as Price
from A
WHERE PRICE1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT PRICE2 as Price
from A
where PRICE1 is null
UNION 
select PRICE3 as id
from A
where PRICE2 is null

select COALESCE (PRICE1,PRICE2,PRICE3) from A

select ISNULL(PRICE1,ISNULL(PRICE2,PRICE3)) from A

select 
case when PRICE1 IS not null then PRICE1 when PRICE1 IS null then PRICE2 WHEN PRICE2 IS NULL then PRICE3 end PRICE id from A
```

None of the above syntax gets the data I'm looking for. Please help

Comment: Are those nulls or blanks.  If they're nulls the coalesce should have worked... if they're blanks they will not.  Try changing the case statement to replace "IS NOT NULL" with "<> ''" and if that solves it, you've got blanks not nulls.

Comment: Was any answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you have empty strings you can try  :

```
select 
  case when coalesce(PRICE1, '') <> '' then PRICE1 
       when coalesce(PRICE2, '') <> '' then PRICE2 
       when coalesce(PRICE3, '') <> '' then PRICE3 
  end AS PRICE 
FROM A
```

Comment: Thanks Forgues, this answers my concern.

Answer (score 11):

Use `COALESCE` like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Price1, Price2, Price3) FROM A;
```

However, this won't work if the entries are blank as opposed to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If your fields could be null or blank, you should check something like this:

```
select Price1 as Price
from A
WHERE PRICE1 IS NOT NULL AND PRICE1 != ''
UNION
SELECT PRICE2 as Price
from A
where PRICE1 is null OR PRICE1 = ''
UNION 
select PRICE3 as id
from A
where (PRICE1 is null OR PRICE1 = '') AND (PRICE2 is null OR PRICE2 = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple if null in first col, look in second, if that is null look in third col.

```
select isnull(PRICE1,isnull(PRICE2,PRICE3)) as Price from A
```